# option belonging to several optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

Is it possible that a `<option>` belongs to many optgroup?

I know that I can do this

```
<select id="menu1">
       <optgroup label="fruit">
            <option value="pomme">pomme</option>
            <option value="kiwi">kiwi</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="exotique">
            <option value="kiwi">kiwi</option>
       </optgroup>
 </select>
```

But this doesn't make my job easy because I need to handle it myself through `javascript`. The hard part is that I'm using multiselect2side, so when the user selects `kiwi` for instance, when he switches to the group `exotique`, it must take into account that kiwi doesn't exist anymore because it was already selected.

The question is, is there a way that html handles that natively?

**UPDATE1**

Actually the `select` in the code above is what the server sends, in my `javascript` script I do this:

```
$('#menu1').multiselect2side({
    search: 'Search: ',
    moveOptions: false,
    labelsx: '* Available *',
    labeldx: '* Selected *',
    autoSort: true,
    autoSortAvailable: true
});
```

And I get two multi select sides with the possibility to pass values from the one side to another.

Comment: you can assign two different values to both option. say `kiwi_0` and `kiwi_1`

Comment: there is no problem you show the result! :)

Comment: I think you are asking if *multiselect2side* natively compares `<option>`s from different `<optgroups`, and that would be a question for the docs. pasting your demo code into a fiddle shows what html natively handles.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I can't actually because the select comes from the server (php), the groups are important only for the users to help them find quickly what they're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$("select").on('change', function(){
  var val=$(this).val();
  $(this).find("option[value="+val+"]").attr("disabled",true);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u12xcy4p/)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for multiselect2side (no tag for this plugin)

Comment: @smarber Can you show your exact HTML..then I can help more

Comment: Updated my post, hope this's clearer but I it's really such a tricky problem since I use `multiselect2side` (a little bit modified) which I don't know very well